# AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges() as root Error

Tags: cocoa, authorization, root, sudo, nstask

I am a beginner in cocoa...

I just want to start Apache and other process in my Cocoa App.

Here is my code :

```
    OSStatus myStatus;
    AuthorizationFlags myFlags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults;
    AuthorizationRef myAuthorizationRef;
    FILE *pipe = NULL;
    myStatus = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, myFlags, &myAuthorizationRef);
    AuthorizationItem myItems = {kAuthorizationRightExecute, 0, NULL, 0};
    AuthorizationRights myRights = {1, &myItems};
    myFlags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | 
    kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
    kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize |
    kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;
    myStatus = AuthorizationCopyPrivilegedReference (&myAuthorizationRef,kAuthorizationFlagDefaults);
    myStatus = AuthorizationCopyRights (myAuthorizationRef,&myRights, NULL, myFlags, NULL ); 

    char *tool = "/usr/sbin/apachectl";
    char *args[] = { "start",NULL} ;    

    myStatus = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(myAuthorizationRef, tool, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, &pipe);
    char c[100];
    int n=fread(c,1,100,pipe);
    c[n] = '\0';
    NSLog(@"%s\n",c);
```

theResult :  ***This operation requires root***
When I run a **'whoami'**, I'm '**root'** but when I run a **getuid()**, I'm '**501'**...

I try to use setuid(0); But it doesn't set !!
Can you help me? 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define access for user with uid=501 access to /usr/sbin/apachectl in /etc/sudoers, and execute "sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl" instead of /usr/sbin/apachectl in the code.

Answer (score 14):

I had this exact same problem. AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges allows you escalate your permission to root, but does not do it automatically (I guess to preserve the user session or whatever).

I ended up making a generic executable that would be run via AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges, and then that executable would setuid to root, and then exec the process you *actually* want to run as root.

Here's the source for the setuid wrapper executable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("not enough arguments\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if (0 != setuid(0)) {
    printf("setuid failed.\n");
    return -3;
  }
  int i;
  char** argvz = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc - 1));
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    argvz[i - 1] = argv[i];
  }

  execv(argv[1], argvz);
  printf("execv returned?\n");
  return -2;
}
```

Then, basically run (calling it via AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges) it as:

```
setuid my-program-to-run and arguments to pass
```

It will setuid as root, and then run the program in question with the args given.

Note that you *must* call setuid from AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges As only the pid that was created by AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges will have escalated privileges (and setuid will exec and replace the process with your own).

Comment: thanks for your answer I cut and pasted it right in!  One error: execv doesn't know how many arguments to expect so need to increase the size of argvz by one and add a null pointer to the end argvz[argc-1] = NULL;  Also can include <unistd.h> and <stdlib.h> to get rid of compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing exactly the same problem !
This is insane that a whoami returns "root" and a root command returns "root required" !!
The sudoers solution may works but I think we would have to search around the setuid bit, as written here https://github.com/notbrien/OSXSlightlyBetterAuth/blob/master/OSXSlightlyBetterAuth.m#L94

Comment: I got the solution...
You just have to create a simple program with an NStask calling your apache command. And this program must begin with setuid(0);
Then build it, and run it through AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges.

Comment: I tried but it does not work. Can you write me a small example... thanks

Comment: I compile this : http://pastebin.com/dTxrCPdg 
Then, I put it in https://github.com/notbrien/OSXSlightlyBetterAuth/blob/master/OSXSlightlyBetterAuth.m#L94